# Positive solutions to Yamabe problem?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Yamabe problem ensures that for any Riemannian metric $g$, in its conformal class $[g]$ there always exists a metric $\bar g$ whose scalar curvature $\bar R$ is constant.

I was wondering whether this is a possible way to find metrics with positive scalar curvature? i.e.,  for a Riemannian metric $g$, in its conformal class $[g]$ does there exist a metric $\bar g$ whose scalar curvature $\bar R$ is positive? If $R$ is positive, this trivial. If $R$ is negative, this is not possible by the conformal change of scalar curvature. If $R$ is positive somewhere and negative somewhere, is it possible to find a solution?

In other words, suppose $\phi>0$, is there a sufficient condition for $f$ such that
$$-\Delta u+fu=\phi$$
has a positive solution?

Comment: I don't understand how your displayed equation has anything to do with the paragraphs above. The conformal change equation for scalar curvature is well-known (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Under_a_conformal_change) or [this article](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1987-17-01/S0273-0979-1987-15514-5/S0273-0979-1987-15514-5.pdf)), and is definitely non-linear. It differs from your linear equation. Did you mean to have a term $u^q$ for some $q$ on the right hand side?

Comment: I use $e^{2h}$ as the conformal factor, and after some change of variable we get an equation of the form that I wrote.

Answer (score 2):

First observe that by the positive solution to the Yamabe problem we can assume that the background metric $g$ has constant scalar curvature $S$. The conformal change of metric formula gives that the new scalar curvature $\tilde{S}$ is given by 
$$ \frac{4(n-1)}{n-2} \triangle_g u + S u = \tilde{S} u^{p-1} $$
where $p = 2n/(n-2)$. When $M$ is compact, we can integrate over $M$ and obtain that 
$$ \int S u = \int \tilde{S} u^{p-1} $$
Observing that the conformal factor needs to be positive, this means that

> **Theorem**: if $g$ has zero or negative Yamabe invariant, there does not exist a conformal metric with positive scalar curvature.

---

For the positive Yamabe class case, we have the following (slightly old) reference (so I don't know if there are more developments). On page 211 of Aubin's *Some nonlinear problems in Riemannian Geometry* you find the assertions that

**Theorem** (p289 of [Aubin's Yamabe paper](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=431287)) If the compact manifold $(M,g)$ is not conformal to the sphere with the standard metric, there exists a constant $k > 1$ (which depends on the manifold) such that any smooth $f$ satisfying $$ 0 < \sup f \leq k \inf f$$ is the scalar curvature of some metric conformal to $g$.

**Theorem** ([Escobar-Schoen](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=856845)) When $n = 3$ and $(M,g)$ not conformal to the sphere with the standard metric, if $\sup f > 0$ then $f$ is the scalar curvature of some metric conformal to $g$.

There are also some other sufficient conditions mentioned in the book which I won't take the time to list here.